# How to protect Java application from internally running custom code?

Tags: java, security, stack-overflow

I develop the container-like application which can accept custom JARs and run some classes from these JAR archives. And I wanr to protect my application from this custom code.

I've found `SecurityManager` and `Policy` classes there, but I still don't know how to protect my application from stack overflow attacks and so on.

I've found `Runtime` class, but I cannot use the separate process because I need to have the instance of the custom class in my application.

What instrument should I use? Or, maybe, I should change the architecture of my application?

Comment: If you're accepting user provided code running in your application, you're frankly asking for trouble. What do you achieve with this functionality?

Comment: I develop something like private cloud, so it is core functionality

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to achieve what Google did with [GAE](https://appengine.google.com). It's not a simple subject to be addressed here so I suppose [this paper](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/woot/tech/final_files/Carlini.pdf) could be of help.

Comment: I've read the article - it is usefull, but there are still some technical questions about isolating instance from the host Java application and implementation basis (should I use `Runtime` with sockets or there are better solutions)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this, it seems better to go for a ["chroot jail"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) or the full [virtualisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system-level_virtualization). (Neither of which I no much about.)